Help identifying a very strange Fraktur character
While leafing through Wilhelm Blaschke's book Vorlesungen Über Differentialgeometrie I, I found two Fraktur characters that I did not recognize. Here is an image from the first one:

Thanks to this answer I identified the character: it is the letter "x" (!!!). The other one still eludes me:


Perhaps this character is the amalgamation of other two, or something like that. I tried the usual tools to determine LaTeX symbols, with no success.

E

The first is lower case x, and the second is upper case E. While the following is not the exact font used, it gives a sample of a font with those two characters with the shapes as you showed.


In the spirit of teaching a person how to fish: for identifying fraktur and calligraphic fonts, the mathalpha documentation is quite convenient as it includes tables showing the output of common math fonts packages.

+1 for "In the spirit of teaching a person how to fish..." :-)
